What is the Proper Way of Interpreting the Story of David and Goliath?
There are a lot of stories, sermons, and commentaries surrounding this passage. Most of them will make an analogy of Goliath as the problems we face. However, there are some who really are against this idea. I will quote a post below regarding it. But my question is, what is your take on interpreting this passage? Is it really a crime for preachers to preach an analogy of goliath as problems in life?
here is the post:
YOU'RE NOT DAVID, AND THAT'S NOT GOLIATH
Sorry, but you're just not. And your "struggle" isn't equivalent to a "Goliath in the life of David." To teach that passage of Scripture as if "David and Goliath" is about you "fighting the giants in your life" is false. The story isn't about you.
It's about David and Goliath.
And if you want to make the story about you, then you should apply all of it-- including David's life of sin.
So, sure. Sometimes God will put a "Goliath" in your life for you to find the "David" within you... so that He can help you find out that the David inside of you is spying on women taking baths and plotting to kill their husbands.
See, we like to interpret the "cool" and "heroic" things of the Bible to be about ourselves, but then we go and throw out everything that convicts us or makes us feel guilty.
The problem is you can't have your cake and eat it too. If you're going to interpret a story about another as being about you, then you don't get the freedom to keep what you like and throw out what you don't like.
Instead, you should just interpret the Bible in its own context, the way God designed it to be interpreted. The story of David and Goliath is about David and Goliath, not you. Sure, there is a universal principle to apply. **But that universal principle is NOT "you are David" and "your problems are giants for you to overcome."
The universal principle is that God is the true King, not just of Israel, but of the whole world, and so we should follow Him, trust Him, and submit our will to His will. (https://www.crossway.org/.../david-and-goliath-is-about.../)
In context, the story of David and Goliath isn't even about their battle. It's about who the true King is; who the true GOD is.
You're not David.
Your problems are not Goliath.
But your God is the true King and Ruler.
So follow Him, trust in Him, and submit your will to His Will.
Lest you not only "slay the giants in your life," but you become a giant you want to slay yourself.
Keep Thinking!

The link doesn't work (it contains "..."s).

SE-BH examines scripture and analyses it hermeneutically. The 'post' above is irrelevant. It would be better to quote the specific part of the narrative you are inquiring about. There will be many and various interpretations of the events. For example, David only used one stone. There are four left. Thus all the oppositions to the God of Israel may be slain, whether from the north, south, east or west.

Here is the link: https://www.crossway.org/articles/david-and-goliath-is-about-more-than-having-courage/

The entire narrative is what is being inquired of from 1 Samuel 17:1- 51

@ManuelZabatII says "Here is the link". That link works, but it is for a different article. ¶ When you do find the correct link, please edit it into the question, not in the comments.

Using Goliath as an analogy for problems is flawed. In the story of David and Goliath, David didn't hesitate to confront Goliath, believing that the Lord, who had saved him from the lion and bear, would also save him from Goliath. Therefore, Goliath was not a problem for David.
1 Samuel 17:37 (NIV)

"The Lord who rescued me from the paw of the lion and the paw of the bear will rescue me from the hand of this Philistine.”

The story of David and Goliath underscores God's almighty power. This is illustrated in 1 Samuel 17:47

All those gathered here will know that it is not by sword or spear that the Lord saves; for the battle is the Lord’s, and he will give all of you into our hands.” (NIV)

A similar event is when Gideon defeated 135,000 Midianite allies with just 300 men (Judges 7). The Lord reduced Gideon's men from 32,000 to 300 to demonstrate that victory comes from God's power, not human strength.
Unlike Gideon, David didn't need signs from the Lord. Zechariah 4:6 encapsulates this teaching;

Not by might nor by power, but by my Spirit,’ says the Lord Almighty. (NIV)

Therefore, using Goliath as an analogy for life's problems implies that those being taught lack faith in God.
